# Open read columns of each line in text file and do (windows)?

Tags: arrays, fortran, multiple-columns

This is the Fortran code that I modified. 
The problem is the code can not open the text file.

I am getting the following error:

```
The message is: RunCode: Fail to run.. At line 123 of file <unit = 90, file = 'cunnette_xyz.txt'> Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

The file is below in 4368 rows (decimals are the same for three columns):

```
602340.440000,129706.190000,28.892939
602340.880000,129706.390000,28.955128
602884.500000,128780.700000,29.876873
602884.380000,128781.190000,29.875114
602884.250000,128781.660000,29.885448
602884.130000,128782.150000,29.895996
602883.940000,128782.630000,29.899380
602883.810000,128783.120000,29.903221
602883.690000,128783.590000,29.907070
602883.560000,128784.080000,29.910931
602883.440000,128784.560000,29.914803
602883.310000,128785.050000,29.918684
602883.190000,128785.520000,29.922575
602883.060000,128786.010000,29.926479
602882.940000,128786.490000,29.930393
602882.810000,128786.980000,29.934317
602882.630000,128787.450000,29.938253
602882.500000,128787.940000,29.942202
.
.
.
```

the program is:
     ----------------------------

```
  USE BIEF
  USE DECLARATIONS_TELEMAC2D
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER LNG,LU, K, ITRAC,I, NSOM,J, NLINE, NDOWN
  DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER:: BATHY_RADIER_up= 29.84D0
  DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER:: DEPTH_up = 2.15D0
  REAL A(5000),B(5000),C(5000)
  DOUBLE PRECISION XPOLYD(14), YPOLYD(14), INPOLYD(14)
  COMMON/INFO/LNG,LU
  DOUBLE PRECISION XPOLY(6), YPOLY(6),COTE_RADIER_up

   NSOM = 6
   XPOLY(1) = 602883.13
   XPOLY(2) = 602886.15
   XPOLY(3) = 602887.15
   XPOLY(4) = 602905.46
   XPOLY(5) = 602902.52
   XPOLY(6) = 602884.13


   YPOLY(1) = 128779.99
   YPOLY(2) = 128780.80
   YPOLY(3) = 128777.12
   YPOLY(4) = 128741.21
   YPOLY(5) = 128739.75
   YPOLY(6) = 128775.96


  AT = 0.D0


  CALL OS( 'X=0     ' , X=U )
  CALL OS( 'X=0     ' , X=V )



  IF(CDTINI(1:10).EQ.'COTE NULLE'.OR.
 *   CDTINI(1:14).EQ.'ZERO ELEVATION') THEN
    CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , H , H  , H , 0.D0 )
    CALL OS( 'X=X-Y   ' , H , ZF , H , 0.D0 )
  ELSEIF(CDTINI(1:14).EQ.'COTE CONSTANTE'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:18).EQ.'CONSTANT ELEVATION') THEN
    CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , H , H  , H , COTINI )
    CALL OS( 'X=X-Y   ' , H , ZF , H , 0.D0   )
  ELSEIF(CDTINI(1:13).EQ.'HAUTEUR NULLE'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:10).EQ.'ZERO DEPTH') THEN
    CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , H , H  , H , 0.D0  )
  ELSEIF(CDTINI(1:17).EQ.'HAUTEUR CONSTANTE'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:14).EQ.'CONSTANT DEPTH') THEN
    CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , H , H  , H , HAUTIN )
  ELSEIF(CDTINI(1:13).EQ.'PARTICULIERES'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:10).EQ.'PARTICULAR'.OR.
 *       CDTINI(1:07).EQ.'SPECIAL') THEN

  COTE_RADIER_up = BATHY_RADIER_up + DEPTH_up

   input for coordinates of the downstream
    NDOWN = 14

  XPOLYD(1) = 602883.13
  XPOLYD(2) = 602886.15
  XPOLYD(3) = 602864.47
  XPOLYD(4) = 602837.90
  XPOLYD(5) = 602821.91
  XPOLYD(6) = 602649.77
  XPOLYD(7) = 602634.35
  XPOLYD(8) = 602345.08
  XPOLYD(9) = 602326.07
  XPOLYD(10) = 602619.31
  XPOLYD(11) = 602638.33
  XPOLYD(12) = 602811.64
  XPOLYD(13) = 602831.52
  XPOLYD(14) = 602857.16


  YPOLYD(1) = 128779.99
  YPOLYD(2) = 128780.80
  YPOLYD(3) = 128867.74
  YPOLYD(4) = 128936.74
  YPOLYD(5) = 128953.95
  YPOLYD(6) = 129105.43  
  YPOLYD(7) = 129143.43
  YPOLYD(8) = 129713.38
  YPOLYD(9) = 129708.26
  YPOLYD(10) = 129136.41
  YPOLYD(11) = 129094.72 
  YPOLYD(12) = 128941.16      
  YPOLYD(13) = 128931.09
  YPOLYD(14) = 128865.81


   DO 10 J=1,NPOIN 
    IF(INPOLY(X(J),Y(J),XPOLY,YPOLY,NSOM)) THEN
          write(lu,*) 'upstream is recognized....'


          H%R(J)=MAX(0.D0,COTE_RADIER_up-ZF%R(J))
          U%R(J)=0.0D0
    ELSE
PRINT *, 'opening file'
  OPEN(unit =90, FILE = 'cunnette_xyz.txt', FORM ='FORMATTED')
  PRINT *, 'read now'
  READ (90, *)NLINE
  PRINT *, 'DO now'


     READ (90, *) A(K),B(K),C(K)
      IF(INPOLY(X(J),Y(J),XPOLYD,YPOLYD,NDOWN)) THEN
        DO K=1,NLINE
          H%R(K)=0.45D0
          U%R(K)=0.D0
        ENDDO
       ELSE
        H%R(J)=0.0D0
        U%R(J)=0.0D0
       ENDIF
    ENDIF
      write(lu,*) 'downstream ....',K,H%r(K)



10    CONTINUE

  ELSE
    IF(LNG.EQ.1) THEN
    WRITE(LU,*) 'CONDIN : CONDITION INITIALE NON PREVUE : ',CDTINI
    ENDIF
    IF(LNG.EQ.2) THEN
    WRITE(LU,*) 'CONDIN: INITIAL CONDITION UNKNOWN: ',CDTINI
    ENDIF
    STOP
  ENDIF


  IF(NTRAC.GT.0) THEN
    DO ITRAC=1,NTRAC
      CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , X=T%ADR(ITRAC)%P , C=TRAC0(ITRAC) )
    ENDDO
  ENDIF



  CALL OS( 'X=C     ' , VISC , VISC , VISC , PROPNU )



  RETURN
  END
```

Comment: It would really help if you could show a complete, compilable program that shows the problem. It would also help if you tell us what error is reported when your program stops. And no, you shouldn't really be using double precision, that is obsolete and has been for a quarter of a century, rather you should be using Real with an appropriate kind.

Comment: @user3707065 Please clean up your post. Currently, it's a mess. Use the code blocks where applicable and give the exact error that you see. Instead of dumping the complete code here, try to narrow it down a little. I'd love to help you, but I'm not going to do all the work for you.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I modified. Please help me. why  the txt file can not be read??

Comment: OK, now you put everything into proper formatting. What does your program do? What are the relevant lines for reading in the data? What is your intent, and what do you get? Which steps did you take to solve the problem? I cannot tell you how to solve the problem is **because you didn't say what problem you have**.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt, this a flow hydrodynamic program to define the initial condition of my flow at time =0s. I want to simulate a dam-break effect. So I have defined two polygone of mesh with nods:1)begore the dam, 2) after the dam. for before the dam every thing is ok til H%R(J)=MAX(0.D0,COTE_RADIER_up-ZF%R(J))
U%R(J)=0.0D0. After, for Else, I want to introduce my second polygone and tel to the program if in this polygone, nods (x,y,z) from the txt file are read and were inside, then : for each node do : H%R(K)=0.45D0 and U%R(K)=0.D0, otherwise, ...So 4368 nods (lines of txt file) should be find.

Comment: That's not the point. You say you cannot open the file. That could be anything from specifying the wrong path to crashing the computer. What error message do you get? Did you compile your code with debug options? What do you get then? Did you check the IO status after opening the file and all read/write operations?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt, sorry I got it. The message is: RunCode: Fail to run.. At line 123 of file <unit = 90, file = 'cunnette_xyz.txt'> Fortran runtime error: End of file

Comment: @AlexanderVogt, how to check the IO status?

Comment: your code expects a single integer numline on the first line of the file

Comment: @agentp, there is : INTEGER LINE, it is not correct?

Comment: i mean it expects an integer to read from the data file. actually i realise thats in the do loop so you are expecting to read an integer every other line.